How would replaceable egg yolk evolve?
Those familiar with Alex Ries' Birrin project probably know that the Birrin as an alien species have unique eggs with a sort of replaceable egg yolk the parent needs to exchange every so often. The reasoning behind it is to incite a parental bond in a precocial species. The yolk, or in this case "protein caps", would be less efficient hence why it needs to be replaced. The egg shell has special adaptations to signal the embryo's nutritional state to the parent through scent and pigmentation. The parent lays a replacement protein cap on regular intervals until the hatchling is born.
As much as I like this conceptually, one has to wonder how this very delicate process would have evolved.
First let's look at evolutionary 'logic' behind it:

The Birrin ancestor's were precocial, meaning their young hatched fully formed. As such the parental instincts to feed the eggs weren't present and must have been acquired through pressure to do so.
The Birrin ancestor's eggs, likely through a defect, lost a significant amount of yolk which would inevitably lead to the loss of the fetus. Already this is the first stopgap for this particular adaptation.
The egg must also have an exposed membrane in order to receive additional nutrition. So two mutations are needed for this adaptation.
The Birrin ancestor must have had the intelligence to feed their defective eggs in order to avoid extinction and therefore losing the trait. I assume the scent and pigmentation adaptation came later to facilitate or make this process possible in the first place. I do not know how developed the Birrin sense of smell is.
The Birrin ancestor must have had a second mutation that made them lay a 'protein cap' essentially an unfertilized egg to then be placed on the defective eggs.

From what I've gathered so far this adaptation sounds like a case of macroevolution. I'm posting this to figure out if there is an explanation that involves microevolution. Thank you and have a good day, friends.

I know nothing about the Birrin project, but plenty precocial species have a parental bond. Horses, antelope, bison and chickens for instance. Is what placental and marsupial mammals do of any interest? Or are you only interested in egg laying animals?

Here on Earth, mammals have evolved an even better strategy: instead of producing a massive one-at-a-time egg yolk, they have a mechanism by means of which the mother supplies continuously the fats, sugars, and proteins the embryo needs. Not to mention that this mechanism also takes care of the embryo's respiratory needs.

The existence of the protein caps are not a problem - that is just 'offspring provisioning' to give the technical term biologists use for provising nutrition for your young. Nature has come up with all sorts of ways of doing this. To name a few: yolk, nutrients passed via the placenta, milk, crop milk, honey, paralysed prey, infertile eggs to eat, letting your babies eat your skin (caecilians), letting your babies cannibalise you (some spiders, some shield bugs), letting your babies cannibalise each other (barn owls, or inside the womb in sand tiger sharks).
The protein caps occur before birth/hatching rather than after, so are more like yolk or placenta than milk or infertile eggs. The weird quirk is that the parent is repeatedly 'feeding' the egg, rather than packaging it all in one go. I know nothing about the Birrin's protein cap manufacture, but the potential hiccup I can see with that 'egg feeding' is that there is a risk of infection/contamination with each feed.
An embryo inside an egg or a womb is sealed safely in a sterile environment. Breaching that sealed environment to pop in some more food risks exposure to bacteria, fungi and parasites. Providing non-sterile food is also a risk, but we can assume if the parent can produce a sterile egg, they can produce a sterile protein cap. They'll just have to also sterilise the surface of the egg very carefully before they glue the next cap on. Like a mother earwig constantly cleans her eggs to avoid fungal infection.
Alternatively... at a certain stage in development the parent might want to provide non-sterile caps, to give the foetus the symbiotic organisms it needs for its gut microbiome.
Your suggested evolutionary sequence is over-complicating things. A species with no parental care evolving into one with parental care has occured tons of times on Earth, so is not unusual. Stage 1 - guard your eggs so predators don't eat them. Stage 2 - guard your newly hatched babies so predators don't eat them (e.g crocodilians). Stage 3 - feed your babies and/or teach then to feed themselves.
The unusual thing is the Birrin's inability to produce enough yolk in one package to sustain an embryo though to hatching. That's a fatal flaw - extinction is inevitable. Therefore the caps must have evolved before things got to that fatal stage. Natural selection then did its usual 'make do and mend' method of working with what you've got.
Let's say the ancestral Birrin provide infertile eggs for their babies to eat as a first meal (trophic eggs) just like various poison frogs and spiders do. Then to save a bit of time and to parcel out the infertile eggs evenly, they took to 'gluing' one infertile egg onto the end of each fertilised egg. The embryo began the hatching process by eating its way out through the 'egg cap'.
(Animals parcelling out resources to offspring is very complicated - there is tons of parent/offspring conflict even before birth, and tons of maternal/paternal conflict which gets fought out on the 'battlefield' of the offspring's genes, depending on which genes were supplied by mum and which by dad, and which are switched on or off. So you have a lot of leeway to invent strategies here). parent-offspring conflict
Then environmental change! Conditions become very poor in terns of food availability, even in the (usually bountiful) late spring/wet season. It becomes a LOT harder to gather and package everything the embryo needs into the yolk and/or everything the hatchling needs into the cap. Solutions are: (1) breed less often, (2) produce smaller clutch sizes, (3) prioritise the yolk, make a smaller cap and hope your babies don't starve when they hatch, (4) prioritise the yolk, make a smaller cap and rush off to feed up so you can slap a second small cap onto the egg later, or (5) some combination of the above.
The second cap (and third, 4th, etc) can be a modifcation of all sorts of existing behaviour. Perhaps they normally laid 2 clutches of eggs per breeding season, but poor conditions mean Mum doesn't have the resources to make another batch of eggs, but she does have enough to make a few more caps. A mother who 'accidentally' produces more caps for a non-existent 2nd clutch and glues them to her first clutch of eggs instead will have more surviving young than one who doesn't. Or perhaps egg and cap production for one clutch is (like birds) spread out over a long period: Monday egg 1, Tuesday cap 1, Wednesday egg 2, Thursday cap 2, Friday egg 3, Saturday cap 3, etc. But she can't produce as many eggs as normal, so on Sunday there is no egg 4 and on Monday she 'mistakenly' glues cap 4 to egg 1.
The only other thing I'd add is that the protein caps need to be more than just protein. Earth biochemistry means you need to use up water to break the nitrogen bond in protein and the egg has a finite supply of water. The caps would be better to have the building blocks (free fatty acids and amino acids) rather than a finished product (protein) which will have to be ripped to pieces and reassembled. But if the protein is just the outer packaging for the building blocks, that's fine.
